# Find the ratio of twelfth terms if the sum of first n terms of two AP's are $3n+8,7n+15$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> The sum of first n terms of two AP's are $3n+8,7n+15$. Then the ratio of their twelfth term is:

$$
\frac{a_{12}}{A_{12}}=\frac{a+11d}{A+11D}=\frac{2a+22d}{2A+22D}=\frac{s_{23}}{S_{23}}=\frac{3(23)+8}{7(23)+15}=\frac{77}{176}=\frac{7}{16}
$$
Fine but if I do the following
$$
a_{12}=s_{12}-s_{11}=44-41
=3\\
A_{12}=S_{12}-S_{11}=99-92=7\\
\frac{a_{12}}{A_{12}}=\frac{3}{7}
$$
Why am I getting diferent results for method 1 and 2 ?. Is the question wrong because the sum of terms of AP is a quadratic expression in $n$ ?

**Note:** This was asked as a multiple choice question with options including both the results of method 1 and 2.

Comment: The question, I assume, must have been "The **ratio of the sum** of first $n$ terms of two AP's are $3n+8,7n+15$ "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should have been

> The **ratio of the** sum of first $n$ terms of two AP's are $3n+8:7n+15$

instead of

> The sum of first $n$ terms of two AP's are $3n+8,7n+15$

Comment: Got it before 20 seconds! (+1)

Comment: @Ak19 Why did you delete yours :-/ ? Its acceptable to keep similar answers if they were not intentionally similar or the same answer were posted after a long time

Comment: We have the same answers!

Comment: How can $x,y$ be a ratio? Do you mean $x:y$?

Comment: yea that makes sense. But I guess the actual question is wrong, unless it is restated as u suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the question is wrong. Either it is not an A.P. or the sum of n terms can't be linear(it can be of the form $S_n=an$ if the common difference is zero).